# Startscript: using $! to create pidfile - returning wrong pid (off by one) occasionally

Tags: shell-script, rhel, daemon, pidfile

We have 3 instances of redis running on a test server.
For some reason, our start script which starts redis can write the wrong pid to a file. Here is what it's doing:

```
su redis -c "redis-server /redis.conf & echo \$! > /var/run/redis_6379"
```

If I chain together `redis_6379 start && redis_6380 start && redis_6381` start 
and then I stop them like that and start them like that, after 10 or 15 iterations I'll encounter a pid in the start file that is off by 1.

Does anyone know why that may occur?

Comment: Which shell are you using? Bash? How exactly are you chaining them? The script you show cannot be run as `redis_6379 start && redis_6380`.

Comment: Oh sorry - Bash, rhel.

Comment: OK, but please show us exactly how you are launching these, what is `redis_6379 start`? Is each of these a script file containing the `redis-server` command you've posted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it possible that `redis-server` forks, and that the PID you get from `$!` is the parent PID, but you're actually interested in the child PID?

Comment: I'm thinking it's something like this. Best way to verify? read the source?

Comment: @JasonG: probably yes. This [posting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8674788/running-redis-in-daemonized-form-and-using-upstart-to-manage-it-doesnt-work) is relevant - it contains a snippet of the redis-server daemonize code, but it's from 2011 though. And it doesn't really explain why this would only happen in one of 10-15 runs.

Comment: @MartinvonWittich - nice detective work!